# Automate import of drawings into network design software then printing to PDF

Tags: pdf, batch, printing, printer, automation

The company I work for uses Stardraw Design 7.1, an AudioVisual design software. However, its level of power-user options seem to be quite limited. I have to import thousands of drawing files to print to PDF using Bullzip PDF Printer. Also setting to Tabloid page size, and setting the margins on all sides to 0.2 inches. You can only import one file at a time, and all of the files have to be printed to PDF separately so that has to be one at a time as well.

This software has no command-line options or any way within to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since Stardraw is CAD style program, I doubt the files are just text.  And since there is no command line, I think you are going to have to spend the time to use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) or similar to achieve what you want.  Basically, you would use it to pretend to be a human and send keystrokes to open file a, select file print, wait xx time or watch for a certain pixel box, close file, open file b, etc.  At least you can preload the filenames as a list in AutoHotKey.

Be careful, though, I've had times where the keystrokes get sent to the wrong program.